# How to gey body() response using RxJava in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

I am new to Kotlin and I am making a method that makes a call to an interface of Endpoints and uses one of the methods present there. I am using `Observable<>` instead of `Call<>` into the response. I wanted to know how to obtain the response body() in the "result" above. This is my method

```
 private fun refreshUser(userLogin: String) {
        executor.execute {
            // Check if user was fetched recently
            val userExists = userDao.hasUser(userLogin, getMaxRefreshTime(Date())) != null
            // If user have to be updated
            if (!userExists) {

                disposable = endpoints.getUser(userLogin)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(
                                { result -> /*Get the response body() HERE*/},
                                { error -> Log.e("ERROR", error.message) }
                        )

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you have defined the `Retrofit` interface. In order to get the `Response` you need to return something from the interface that looks like:

`fun getUsers() : Observable<Response<User>>`

Then inside `{ result -> /*Get the response body() HERE*/}`, you will get something of the form `Response<User>`, which has the response's body.

Also to note, you do not need to enclosing `executor` if you leverage `Room` for the `dao` interactions; it has RxJava support. You can use RxJava operators to combine the `dao` lookup with the server call.

Comment: I have that return type in my interface endpoint. So I wanted to know what to put inside the ( result -> ) to obtain the body, can you show a code example? @Emmanuel

Comment: `result` is the object that is passed into the lambda; the `Response<>` instance in this case. `result.body()` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxandroid-and-kotlin-part-1-f0382dc26ed8

```
//Kotlin
Observable.just("Hello World")
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) 
          //each subscription is going to be on a new thread.
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())) 
          //observation on the main thread
          //Now our subscriber!
          .subscribe(object:Subscriber<String>(){
            override fun onCompleted() {
             //Completed
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
             //TODO : Handle error here
            }

            override fun onNext(t: String?) {
             Log.e("Output",t);
            }
           })
```

if you wanna use retrofit 2 and rxjava 2

https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890

```
interface WikiApiService {

    @GET("api.php")
    fun hitCountCheck(@Query("action") action: String,
                      @Query("format") format: String,
                      @Query("list") list: String,
                      @Query("srsearch") srsearch: String): 
                  Observable<Model.Result>

}
```

Observable is the class response.

```
private fun beginSearch(srsearch: String) {
  disposable = 
     wikiApiServe.hitCountCheck("query", "json", "search", srsearch)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(
       { result -> showResult(result.query.searchinfo.totalhits) },
       { error -> showError(error.message) }
      )
}
```

Comment: He is asking specifically about Retrofit

Comment: I want to use retrofit

Answer (score 0):

If, as you mentioned to @Emmanuel, the return type of your `getUser()` method is `Observable<Response<User>>` then calling `result.body()` will yield the resulting `User`.

```
{ result ->
    val user: User = result.body()
}
```

If however, you are looking for the the raw response, you can instead call `result.raw().body()`; which will return an [`okhttp3.ResponseBody`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html) type.

```
{ result ->
    val body: ResponseBody = result.raw().body()
    val text: String = body.string()
}
```